# Is there a way to specify image dimensions in a request to my S3 storage server?

Tags: amazon-s3, three.js

I have high resolution images stored in s3, but I am building a viewer, and on most devices these images are much higher resolution than what would be feasible for performance on most devices/network delay. I am building a viewer in THREEJS, and threejs's performance is hurt by the number of pixels when mapping these images onto a texture. Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: Have you considered to store images with different quality level on S3 and then request then most appropriate from the client?

Comment: You would need to build that functionality yourself, or you can use third-party services like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/).